# CentOS 6.9 I removed libcom_err - how to restore it?

Tags: centos, yum

I have a CentOS 6.9 x64 server. yum update was failing because of an issue with the libcom_err package (something about conflicting dependencies). I decided I'd try to remove libcom_err and then re-install it and see if that would fix my issues. Turns out that was a very bad idea. After removing the libcom_err package (and it removed some other dependencies like e2fsprogs, libss, mysql_devel, krb5-devel, libcom_err-devel), that kind of broke everything.

I think I need to download this file and then install it manually on my server:
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/libcom_err-1.41.12-23.el6.x86_64.rpm

Except, since libcom_err is gone nothing works. I can't run yum, wget, or curl.

What should I do? I'm feeling kind of lost here, and I'd do a clean install except my backup utility is also broken because libcom_err is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by booting a live CD and downloading the mentioned rpm file onto the server. Then installing via rpm -i.